# blackberry.location.latitude: i am always getting 0 why?/

Tags: javascript, blackberry

```
<html> 
<body> 
<script language="Javascript"> 
if(blackberry.location.GPSSupported) {
blackberry.location.setAidMode(1);
blackberry.location.refreshLocation();
blackberry.location.onLocationUpdate(window.alert("Your new
position is " + blackberry.location.latitude +
" degrees latitude and " +
blackberry.location.longitude +
" degrees longitude."));
}
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I have tested on device **blackberry 8800** and **blackberry 9000** and i am getting always `0` for 
`blackberry.location.latitude` and `blackberry.location.longitude`

**Note:**

- javascript support is enabled
- javascript location support is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this thread on [blackberryforums](http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-legacy-device-discussion/23544-7130e-gps-location-based-services.html)